# Multinomial coefficient formula

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

I was reading about multinomial coefficient, when found this:

$\frac{N!}{k_1!\cdot k_2!\cdot k_3!}=\frac{N!}{(k_1+k_2)!\cdot k_3!}\cdot\frac{(k_1+k_2)!}{k_1!\cdot k_2!}$

Can someone show and explain me missing steps between this expressions?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I write
$\frac{a}{b\cdot c} = \frac{a}{d\cdot c} \cdot \frac{d}{b}$
do you see the similarities?